# how can I remove the area around a TabPane in javaFx?

Tags: javafx-8, stage

I have a simple problem. in the figure you can see, what I need. there is an area above and the left of `tab`, How can I eradicate that?

Sample Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add following CSS for tab Pane..

```
.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0, 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0;
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em;
}
```

Comment: @Delsa Please accept the answer since it worked for you.